# In regex, when using star, can you make some stars, in the regex being repeated, repeat the same number of times?

Tags: regex, repeat

Sorry for the long-winded question. It's probably best to show an example.

I'm trying to match a matrix as a string:

1. `[[]]`
2. `[[][][]]`
3. `[[0][1][2]]`
4. `[[,,][,,][,,]]`
5. `[[0,1,2][3,4,5]]`

Although regex is rarely pretty to look at, this is what I have come up with:

```
\[(\[-?(\d+(\.\d*)?)*(,-?(\d+(\.\d*)?)*)*\])+\]
```

It matches everything. HOWEVER the commas must always be repeated n times. If there are 5 commas, then 4 commas, then 6 commas, it's not a valid matrix. Is there a flag or variables I can use? Or is it outside the scope of regex?

Comment: No, regex doesn't have memory like this. You can match the exact thing that was matched earlier using backreferences, but you can't get information about the match.

Comment: A single regex cannot do the job. You can, however, pick out the first group, count the number of `,`, then construct a regex to validate the rest.

Comment: Which language are you using around the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a regular expression cannot do that.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Use_of_lemma) is a formal proof that a very similar case to yours is not possible. It proves that the language L = {a<sup>n</sup>b<sup>n</sup> : n ≥ 0} is not a "regular language", so it cannot be matched with a regular expression. That language is essentially `a*b*` with the two stars repeating the same number of times. Your case also involves a star repeating the same number of times, so it's also not possible.

In your case the best option is probably to use a regexp to match each "row" of the matrix, that is: do a global search for `\[([^][]*)\]`, for each match grab group 1, which is the row's content, then count the number of commas and compare all the counts (or do a split on comma, using your language's split operation, if you actually need the numbers.)

PS: `[^][]` is the character class of all chars except open and close brackets. The closing bracket needs to be the first char after the ^, it's a special case.